# Save column of numbers from url to python array

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, https

I want to save the data column from [this](https://adventofcode.com/2019/day/1/input) url to an array in python. I tried it with, for instance, pandas.save_table:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_table('https://adventofcode.com/2019/day/1/input', sep='')
```

but I get `HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request` and I think this is not the right way to do that.
Can someone help me with that?

Comment: It is difficult to help you when you don't tell us **how** exactly you tried to do it (post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) and **what** exactly did not work out (post the error message). https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ok, no problem. I thought what I have tried was not going to help that much, because it's probably way too wrong... But thanks for your advice

Answer (score 1):

If you try to open the link in your question (in a browser using incognito mode or something similar i.e. delete your cookies) you'll see that you need login into the website to access the page. This is why the you're getting a `400 Bad Request` error as a response from the server.

From the FAQ section of the website that you're trying to access:

> How does authentication work? Advent of Code uses OAuth to confirm
>   your identity through other services. When you log in, you only ever
>   give your credentials to that service - never to Advent of Code. Then,
>   the service you use tells the Advent of Code servers that you're
>   really you. In general, this reveals no information about you beyond
>   what is already public; here are examples from Reddit and GitHub.
>   Advent of Code will remember your unique ID, names, URL, and image
>   from the service you use to authenticate.

The website uses OAuth to handle logins to the url that you create will need these access tokens. You can use a library like `python-oauth2` to help you with this (there are others so you can read around and decide which you'd like to use). Creating and understanding how to make http requests is beyond the scope of this answer. I'd suggest you have a look around on the internet for some explanations and try again, if you have get stuck please ask another question. Otherwise it'll probably be easier to save the file from your browser...But I'll leave this answer here for the next person who runs into the same problem.